# External hard drive does not mount properly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need help with something, i've moved to Ubuntu last Friday (thats why this stupid question) and deleted windows for good(i was tired of it) but i have this wd external hard drive with 500gbytes that refuses to mount : ) i know that there are loads of tutorials on how to do it but i just dont want to loose everything i have inside the hard disk the error i get is the following:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 12: Failed to read last sector (976771119): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Thanks a lot in advance guys and sorry about the questions i just moved to Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, it should be migrated to another forum.  In meanwhile, you could edit the output of "fdisk -l /dev/sdc" into your question, and also show the exact mount command that you used, and any /dev/sdc lines from /etc/fstab .

Comment: Trying running `fsck` on the device, however being NTFS you may, however, need to repair the filesystem from Windows.